# Not able to implement hide and show functionality with django

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, django, python-3.x

My functionality is that I have a radio button in my form. If user clicks Yes, he should get an error on the screen suggesting that this is not a right place to submit your data and suggest him to visit other website.

In case he clicks No, all the other fields in the form should become visible and mandatory.

My issue is when I click on No  and try to submit without filling all the fields in the form, form gets reloaded and fields are hidden again. Yes, the data is not getting saved in the DB and when I click No, fields are displayed again with errors highlighted.

My main concern is when I click No and all the fields are displayed, I don't want them to be hidden again until the form is submitted successfully or user click Yes.
I need a solution so that form gets reloaded only when all the fields are correct and submitted successfully to the DB.

I will also share the code that I have written so far for better understanding:

1)  models.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models
from bokeh.themes import default
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

# Create your models here.
class MyModel(models.Model):
    CHOICES = (
        ('Yes', 'Yes'),
        ('No', 'No'),
    )

    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=CHOICES, blank=False, null=False)
    field2 = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=CHOICES, blank=False, null=False)
    field3 = models.CharField(max_length=240, blank=True, null=True)
    field4 = models.CharField(max_length=240, blank=True, null=True)
    field5 = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=CHOICES, blank=True, null=True)
    field6 = models.CharField(max_length=240, blank=True, null=True)
    field7 = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=CHOICES, blank=True, null=True)
    field8 = models.CharField(max_length=480, blank=True, null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.id
```

2) forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.core.validators import EMPTY_VALUES
from .models import MyModel

class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    CHOICES = (
        ('Yes', 'Yes'),
        ('No', 'No'),
    )


field1 = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES, widget=forms.RadioSelect())
field2 = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES, widget=forms.RadioSelect())
field3 = forms.CharField(required=False)
field4 = forms.CharField(required=False)
field5 = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES, widget=forms.RadioSelect(), required=False)
field6 = forms.CharField(required=False)
field7 = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES, widget=forms.RadioSelect(), required=False)
field8 = forms.CharField(required=False)
user_input_textbox1 = forms.CharField(max_length=200, widget=forms.HiddenInput(), required=False)

def clean(self):
    field1 = self.cleaned_data.get('field1')
    field2 = self.cleaned_data.get('field2')

    if field2 == 'Yes':
        self._errors['is_tangible_materials_exchanged'] = self.error_class([
            'Please submit a ABC request instead'])

    if field2 == 'No':
        # validate field3
        field3 = self.cleaned_data.get('field3', None)
        if field3 in EMPTY_VALUES:
            self._errors['field3'] = self.error_class([
                'field3 is required here'])

        #validate field4 
        field4 = self.cleaned_data.get('field4', None)
        if field4 in EMPTY_VALUES:
            self._errors['field4'] = self.error_class([
                'field4 is required here'])

        #validate field5
        field5 = self.cleaned_data.get('field5', None)
        if field5 in EMPTY_VALUES:
            self._errors['field5'] = self.error_class([
                'field5 is required here'])

        if field5 == 'Yes':
            # validate field6
            field6 = self.cleaned_data.get('field6', None)
            if field6 in EMPTY_VALUES:
                self._errors['field6'] = self.error_class([
                    'field6 is required here'])


        # validate field7
        field7 = self.cleaned_data.get('field7', None)
        if field7 in EMPTY_VALUES:
            self._errors['field7'] = self.error_class([
                'The purpose of exchanging this confidential information required here'])

        if field7 == 'Yes':
            # validate field8
            field8 = self.cleaned_data.get('field8', None)
            if field8 in EMPTY_VALUES:
                self._errors['field8'] = self.error_class([
                    'field8 is required here'])

    return self.cleaned_data


class Meta:
    model = MyModel
    exclude = ('user',)
```

3) Javascript / jQuery logic

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //hide all
        $(".hidden-md").hide();
        $(".hidden-lg").hide();
        $(".hidden-xs").hide();


        $("input[name='field2']").change(function () {//change event on radio button
            if (this.value == 'No') {
                $(".hidden-md").show();     
            }
            else {
                $(".hidden-md").hide();
                $(".hidden-lg").hide();
                $(".hidden-xs").hide(); 
                $("input[name='field5']").prop('checked', false);
                $("input[name='field7']").prop('checked', false);
            }
        });

        $("input[name='field5']").change(function () {//click event on radio button
            if (this.value == 'Yes') {
                $(".hidden-lg").show();
            }
            else {
                $(".hidden-lg").hide();
            }
        });

        $("input[name='field7']").change(function () {//click event on radio button
            if (this.value == 'Yes') {
                $(".hidden-xs").show();
            }
            else {
                $(".hidden-xs").hide();
            }
        });
    });

    document.getElementByClassName("btn").addEventListener("click", function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        handleFireButton();
    });
</script>
```

Any help or advises will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve my issue.
I implemented my solution using an additional hidden field.
Please find below the solution for this problem:

1) Add a hidden field in forms.py as below:

```py
source = forms.CharField(max_length=50, widget=forms.HiddenInput(), required=False)
```

2) updated Javascript / jQuery logic:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //hide all
        if($("#id_source").val()!="postback" ) {
            $(".hidden-md").hide();
            $(".hidden-lg").hide();
            $(".hidden-xs").hide();
            $("#id_source").val("postback");
        }

        if ($('#id_field2_0').is(':checked') || $("input[name='field2']").is(':checked') == false) {
            $(".hidden-md").hide();
            $(".hidden-lg").hide();
            $(".hidden-xs").hide();
            $("input[name='field5']").prop('checked', false);
            $("input[name='field7']").prop('checked', false);   
        }

        if ($("input[name='field5']").is(':checked') == false || $('#id_field5_1').is(':checked')) {
            $(".hidden-lg").hide(); 
            $("#id_field6").html('');
        }

        if ($("input[name='field7']").is(':checked') == false || $('#id_field7_1').is(':checked')) {
            $(".hidden-xs").hide(); 
            $("#id_field8").html('');
        }

        $("input[name='field2']").click(function () {//change event on radio button
            if (this.value == 'No') {
                $(".hidden-md").show();     
            }
            else {
                $(".hidden-md").hide();
                $(".hidden-lg").hide();
                $(".hidden-xs").hide(); 
                $("input[name='field5']").prop('checked', false);
                $("input[name='field7']").prop('checked', false);
            }
        });

         $("input[name='field5']").click(function () {//click event on radio button
            if (this.value == 'Yes') {
                $(".hidden-lg").show();
            }
            else {
                $(".hidden-lg").hide();
                $("#id_field6").html('');
            }
        });

        $("input[name='field7']").click(function () {//click event on radio button
            if (this.value == 'Yes') {
                $(".hidden-xs").show();
            }
            else {
                $(".hidden-xs").hide();
                $("#id_field8").html('');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Using the above logic, I am able to implement hide and show functionality with jquery/django and though form is reloaded it solves my issue and satisfies the functionality I am looking for.

Regards,

Amey Kelekar

Answer (score 0):

Dinamic logic after your template is already loaded you will achieve with Javascript not with Django, because Django process your request one time and send it to your web browser, so if you trying to show and hide things only with django you will have to reload your page everytime...

Create one function in javascript (or Jquery if you are beginner, jquery is really easy) so you can implement your logic when you want to show or hide inputs

https://www.w3schools.com/jS/default.asp

https://www.w3schools.com/Jquery/default.asp

**EDIT:** To avoid your form to keep sending the data to backend without you validate it you should stop the default action so do something like that

```
$("#btn_submit").click((e) => {
    e.preventDefault(); // This will make your button to submit it
    ... // Validade your logic here
    $("#form_id").submit()
});
```

Talking about hide and show, its realy easy to do

```
$("#chk_a").click(function(e){
    if(this.checked) {
        $(".group_b").hide(); // hide everything from group B

        $("#input_a").show();
        $("#button_a").show();
        $("#somethingelse_a").show();
    }
});

// Same logic to group b

<input id="chk_a">
<input id="input_a" class="group_a">
<input id="button_a" class="group_a">
<input id="somethingelse_a" class="group_a">

<input id="chk_b">
<input id="input_b" class="group_b">
<input id="button_b" class="group_b">
<input id="somethingelse_b" class="group_b">
```

Comment: Hi Diego, I have already written a jquery function and code is shared in my question. My issue is when I click on submit and even if there are errors that few of the mandatory field values are not provided, all the fields get hidden again on click of submit. I have to manually click on No again and only then the fields are displayed and even the error saying that this field is required is displayed. I want the page to be refreshed/reloaded only when all the values are correct and submitted to the DB.

Comment: i edited my answer, check it if give your any direction

Comment: If you dont want you page be reloaded before data being submitted to DB so your only approach is javascript (jquery or vanilla)

Comment: Hi Diego, When you say validate your logic here do you mean to write validation logic or toggling of fields logic over there.

Comment: Validate your logic means what you want to do before the code is sended to your backend... add custom values, check form values, inputs, data format and things arround that, when everyone is set and good to go you submit your form against your atribute action in form, so your backend

Comment: if in my template i do division by 2 numbers, i d like to check if any number is 0 before send that to my backend and crash... of course you can handle it by your backend, but in my projects i like to validate in front and in back